# Comparison evaluation or comparative evaluation?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-request, modifiers

> I am writing my thesis. Now, I am writing analysis the chapter. In the
>   first part of the chapter, results are analyzed. Then in the second
>   part, *refined results of the same data are going to analyze*. So, under
>   second analysis, I want to explain the new results. But since I used
>   same data and same analysis techniques, if I describe the analysis
>   result in a same way to as I wrote earlier then it is repeating. It is difficult to change the contents as I used same analysis techniques.
>   Therefore, I want to write this second analysis as a comparison and
>   showing improvements. First sub heading for my analysis is
>   “***Geometrical evaluation***”.
>
> At the moment, for the second sub heading, I used “***Comparative
>   evaluation on object geometry***”.  I am doubted whether this topic
>   reflects some other meaning as the word ***comparison*** is not there.
>   If I write ***comparison evaluation on object geometry***, then would
>   it be more meaningful or not?

Could you please give me some suggestions? Any other titles are always welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Comparison evaluation of object geometry

Sounds like an evaluation of different comparisons - as if you're evaluating multiple methods of comparing the data rather than evaluating the data itself.

> Comparative evaluation of original vs. refined object geometry

An evaluation that explicitly compares and evaluates the 2 sets of data: the original and the refined (subset?).

Hard to say for certain without a better understanding of the topic, but a "comparative evaluation" sounds more standard & correct for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> Comparative evaluation

is OK. You are describing what kind of evaluation you are doing, comparing two evaluations. So using the adjective form *comparative* is fine.

I can't say if *comparison evaluation* is wrong, but it sounds strange to me.

Take a look at the definition for [comparative](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/comparative) sense 1.